# SQL query for below data

Tags: mysql, sql

For input, When quantity value greater then 1, convert in a new row with value 1 for quantity column.

```
INPUT
ID         ProductFK         Quantity       Price
------------------------------------------------
10         1                  2           100
11         2                  3           150
12         1                  1           120

OUTPUT
ID        ProductFK         Quantity        Price
------------------------------------------------
10        1                   1          100
10        1                   1          100
11        2                   1          150
11        2                   1          150
11        2                   1          150
12        1                   1          120
```

Comment: MySQL is not PostgreSQL. Use only the tag for the product you're using

Comment: Please specify your database either mysql or postgresql. What is the maximum limit of quantity? Also why do you want the result in this way?

Comment: removed postgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using a sequence table trick.  Inner join your current table to a sequence on the condition that the quantity be greater than or equal to the sequence value.  For example:

```sql
SELECT t1.ID, t1.ProductFK, 1 AS Quantity, t1.Price
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 AS Quantity UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) t2
    ON t1.Quantity >= t2.Quantity
ORDER BY t1.ID;
```

### Demo